# how to make full html page as pfd in django

Tags: html, django

i have a html page in my django templates, its a pdf type, the `for loop` should make a `transactions` based on the number of which the  `object model returns`, however i want every `transaction` to be in a full html page, and the other `transaction` come net page, i have tried to do it but seems a bit hard since im new to django html.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    {% block title %}   Report  {% endblock title %}

        <div id="container">

        
    {% block content %}
    
   {% for transaction in transactions %}
    {% if transaction.complete %}
      
    
   


<table class="tg">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="tg-fv77" colspan="12" rowspan="2"><span style="color:#3531FF">Report For Tenant ( {{ transaction.chp_reference }} )</span></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-0pky" colspan="9">CHP Reference</td>
            <td class="tg-0pky" colspan="3">{{transaction.chp_reference}}</td>
 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-0pky" colspan="9">Rent Effective From (dd/mm/yyyy)</td>
            <td class="tg-0pky" colspan="3">{{transaction.rent_effective_date}}</td>

        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="9">CRA Fortnightly Rates valid for 6 months from</td>
            <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">{{transaction.cra_rate_from}}</td><hr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="9">Market Rent of the Property</td>
            <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">{{transaction.property_market_rent}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="9">Number of Family Group(s)</td>
            <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">{{transaction.number_of_family_group}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

{% if transaction.complete %}
  


<table class="tg" style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 714px">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 86px">
        <col style="width: 201px">
        <col style="width: 109px">
        <col style="width: 63px">
        <col style="width: 121px">
        <col style="width: 134px">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {% for f in transaction.family_groups.all %}
            <th style="text-align:left">Family No</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">Income Type</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">Name</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">Rent %</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">Weekly Income</th>
            <th style="text-align:left"><span style="background-color:#ffe0c7">Rent Component</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-4erg">{{f.name}}</td>
            <td >{% for m in f.family_members.all %}{{ m.num_of_family_members }}<br>{% endfor %}</td>
            <td >{% for m in f.family_members.all %} {{m.name}} <br> {% endfor %}</td>
            <td class="tg-4erg">{% for m in f.family_members.all %} {{m.effective_rent_percentage}} <br> {% endfor %}
            </td>
            <td class="tg-4erg">{% for m in f.family_members.all %} {{m.income}} <br> {% endfor %}</td>
            <td class="tg-1qbe">{% for m in f.family_members.all %} {{m.income_component|stringformat:".2f"}} <br> {% endfor %}</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-0pky" colspan="9">CHP Reference</td>
            <td class="tg-0pky" colspan="3">{{transaction.chp_reference}} Insufficient Info.</td>

 <hr>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
{% endif %}
</table>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
    </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a html file to a pdf using `xhtml2pdf`.There are many other alternatives to it as well.

```
    from django.template.loader import get_template,render_to_string
    import xhtml2pdf.pisa as pisa
    from io import BytesIO

    def render_to_file(path: str, params: dict):
        template = get_template(path)
        html = template.render(params)
        file_name = "report.pdf"
        file_path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname("__file__")), "charts", file_name)
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as pdf:
            pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), pdf, link_callback=BASE_DIR + '/static/charts/Logo/')
        return [file_name, file_path]
```

where 'path' is the path to your html template and params is the contect dictionary (transaction data in your case).

Do read the documentation of xhtml2pdf as it doesn't support all the css that you would apply to a normal html page.

Comment: I have already done this part,  im asking for how to loop each transaction in the html page  in full page, so every transaction will be displayed in like A4 form